# How can I release apk for older Android version in Ionic 4?

Tags: ionic4

How can I release apk for older Android version in Ionic 4?

I've tried with crosswalk, but it does not work in Ionic 4.

```js
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you provide more details? Which "older version" you are targeting?

Comment: Yes, I'll note that.